# What are some alternative phrases to say "for more information"?

Tags: synonyms

Lets say, I have written a answer on SE and I have added some citations at the end of it. What words should I use to refer to it (except for more information)? I generally use the following:

> For more information, refer to:
>
> 1. [citation]
> 2. [citation]

What other words or phrases may I use to express the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two shorthand notes that are used in scholarly writing could come in useful here:

1. **cf.**

> The abbreviation cf. derives from the Latin verb *conferre*, to bring together (from which confer is the conjugation of the imperative form), while in English it is commonly read as "compare". The abbreviation advises readers to consult other material, usually for the purpose of drawing a contrast.

2. **Viz.**

> The abbreviation viz. (or viz without a full stop), short for the Latin videlicet, is used as a synonym for "namely", "that is to say", "to wit", or "as follows". **It is typically used to introduce examples or further details** to illustrate a point.